# How to retrieve nested data in Local Storage using GTM Javascript Gloval Variable

Tags: local-storage, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to retrieve some data from Local Storage by using GTM 'Javascript Variable' variable type.

[image]

It uses dot notation to access the data. It works fine for data that is not nested, it doesn't work for nested data.

```
localStorage.ajs_user_traits.0.name
```

And

```
localStorage.ajs_user_traits.name
```

None of them work, result is 'undefined''

Does anyone knows what might be happening?

Comment: localStorage is key value pairs, are you stringifying the objects? Can you add in a screenshot of localStorage from Chrome dev tools?

Comment: Hi, added screenshot in main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "object" is stored as a string in localStorage. You need to parse it back into json before accessing the name value. You need to create a "Custom JavaScript" variable instead and do something like this:

```
function(){
  var myObjStr = localStorage.getItem('ajs_user_traits'); // fetch key with string of json object
  var myObj = JSON.parse(myObjStr) //turn string into json object
  return myObj.name //return name
}
```